# (web game) text-based combat system shows progress to client instead of give a report at the end

Tags: multiplayer, rpg

I am developing a text-based multiplayer-RPG using React and dotNet core. The fight logic is handled on server side. Basically what `fight()` does is:

- a while loop that iterate 100 times; in each iteration the characters attack each other; actions are stored in a string list
- a winner is determined either at the end of the while loop or one's hp is below 0
- write the fight result and rewards into database
- send response back to client with the combat log (that string list)

This is what the `fight()` basically does. Players clicks fight and get the result and the report instantly. I would like to make the fight more engaging to the players by showing the fight's progress in each round (and add time interval between rounds).

I don't know how to achieve this. I would appreciate any ideas you share.

I could let the client side see a "replay" of the fight using the response from the server, but that's not what I want. Maybe this is something other idle games are doing. I don't know since I don't have much experience of game developing.

Comment: maybe create loop on client side which will run every iteration on server size - and then in this loop on client side you can display result for every iteration and sleep between iterations.

Comment: What is it about the replay that differs from what you want? Are you concerned about delay? For typical server latency that should be easy to cover with a very short intro animation.

Comment: As mentioned, your fight method is likely instantaneous. Run it, send the log to the client and let the client handle the pacing of the fight. (You'll likely eventually need a button "skip to the end" because some players are in a hurry anyway.)

Comment: @Vaillancourt Is it what those idle games are doing now (the result is already made on the server. The client's job is just to replay it)?

Comment: I don't know :) the only idle game I played was cookie clicker and it was completely client based.

Comment: You say you don't want the client to "replay" the fight. Why is it so? Can the player cancel the fight in the middle of it? Can they perform actions that would change the course of it?

Comment: @Vaillancourt The fight doesn't take any action from client once it starts. When I came up with the "Replay" idea, I was like: "no way it can be this easy... Maybe the players want live feedbacks"

Comment: but i think it's ok to use replay in a idle game since it's not like a fps game that requires live feedbacks

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Ty all

Comment: And for the client there is no difference between a replay of the fight or getting the update one by one. If there is no user input, how can the player even know that it is a replay? For all he knows it is a live fight.

Comment: @nkforce Exactly. If the user cannot change the outcome, then from the player's perspective there's no obvious difference between the client getting the outcome as a report & revealing it piece by piece or the server delivering it to the client piece by piece. You could even post that as an answer to your own question ;)